# Why following code is not looping through m?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

The following code is not outputting the desired result. It is only getting iterated through n, not y. Why and how to fix it?

```
int product(int m,int n){
    int x,p;
    while(m>=100){
        while(n>=100){
            printf("Value of m= %d and n=%d\n",m,n );
            x=m*n;
            p=palindrome(x);
            if (p==0)
            {
                printf("These two numbers are %d and %d\n",m,n );

            }
            n--;
        }
        m--;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you decrement the first time through the inner loop, which eventually will fail the whole condition n>=100, assuming n is greater than 100 to start with.

Comment: "It is only getting iterated through n, not y". What y ? A variable?

Answer (score 4):

Because `n' is not any more  >= 100. So the external loop iterates but is never entering the internal after the first one.

The solution:  ***Be careful!!!!*** - if you execute it online you will kill your browser :)

```
int product(int m,int n){
    int x,p, savedn = n;
    while(m>=100){
        while(n>=100){
            printf("Value of m= %d and n=%d\n",m,n );
            x=m*n;
            p=palindrome(x);
            if (p==0)
            {
                printf("These two numbers are %d and %d\n",m,n );

            }
            n--;
        }
        m--;
        n = savedn;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,Now I realize my mistakes.